# VS 2017 extension with javascript/nodejs

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Is it possible to develop a Visual Studio 2017 extension with JavaScript or nodeJs?

I already have a VSCode extension and want to reuse my code (see marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JaimeOlivares.yuml)

If so, is there any code sample?

Comment: Which kind of feature do you want to add in your extension? As you said that it has one for the VS code, whether it already has this feature in VS or any other extension in VS? If possible, please share us the detailed features you want to add to your VS IDE, so we can do research for it.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT My question pretends to be generic but my personal use-case is: marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JaimeOlivares.yuml

Comment: Not found the extension in VS, but VS has the default feature like to create UML modeling projects and diagrams: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409445.aspx

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, that's why I want to port my own extension to VS. I am not looking for the UML functionality, I am looking for the way to implement my extension in VS.